# Using .config files to load models in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I have a .config file, name being ssd_mobilenet_v1.config which I know is supposed to load a pretrained model from tensorflow. However, I am unable to find how to do that.

I have searched the internet and there are instructions to do so from a dict but not directly using a .config file

Comment: You can follow the IPYNB notebook in [this](https://github.com/TannerGilbert/Tensorflow-Object-Detection-with-Tensorflow-2.0) repo.